# How to join 3 tables in postgresql via with statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

Cannot get this sql to run .  keeps saying seat_group_unique_id doesn't exist.  I am trying to find out if items currently on sale match in table midas_input_indexed with inventory, but inventory table doesn't have a column `seat_group_unique_id`

```
with allonsale as (select seat_group_unique_id, event_unique_id ) 
select * from allonsale  a1 
left join recommendations.midas_input_indexed a2 on a1.seat_group_unique_id = a2.seat_group_unique_id
left join ticketing.seat_groups a3 on a3.seat_group_unique_id = a2.seat_group_unique_id
left join ticketing.inventory a4 on a4.event_unique_id = a3.event_unique_id
and a1.event_unique_id = a3.event_unique_id  
where a2.seat_group_unique_id is null
```

Comment: `select seat_group_unique_id, event_unique_id`

is not complete sql statement. Yes it doesn't exists.

Comment: BTW: It always helps to explain the tables. Especially their unique keys and how they are related. You have many joins there and `select *`. Do you really want to show all columns from all four tables involved? And it looks like you are trying an anti join on a2 here, but why then would you outer join a3 and a4 to a2? And why would you do an anti join in the first place rather than a straight-forward `not exists`? Please explain what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: As Simonare pointed out, you need a from clause in your cte (with statement)

Answer (score 0):

your SQL needs to add something you are missing: a FROM statement and the table you want to retrieve the data from.

```
with allonsale as (select seat_group_unique_id, event_unique_id FROM yourtable)
```

(...)

You will find all the information in the POSTGRESQL official website:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html